# the timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool

Tags: sql-server, connection-pooling, load-testing, connection-timeout, max-pool-size

We have a web application and we are performing **load test of 250 users** on the application. Its working perfectly in one environment without any error logs or error generated. and it another environment its not working and throwing below error.

Please note that server specifications are exactly similar for SQL server and Application server. Only there are 2 separate environments.
[image]
We have `SQL server` Enterprise edition and `IIS 8` as application server on both machines. Application and DB server are on separate machines for both the environments. All the settings are similar too.

PS: Please do not suggest anything for closing connections etc. Have already reviewed the code. All the connections are being closed by `using` keyword and `connection.close()` method. Its already in place.

Comment: Have you tried doing the same transaction manually on both environments? What happened?

Comment: The scenario is based on 250 concurrent user simulate..i tried accessing both the environments with couple of users and its working like charm...But only in case of 250 user simulations there is a problem....What else could be there..?

Comment: It would seem then that the the two environments are different. You need to find or explain the differences. Changing from 2 users to 250 has not told you anything useful, except "it doesn't work". I suggest a step load, start at 1, increment by 5 every minute until reaching 250. Then you get some idea of where it breaks.